# SQL Join Rows to column

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have left join between two tables where it returns two records I need that record should be converted from rows to column.

SQL join as follows:

```
select (case when l.PatientVisitCluster=1 then t.Result end) as t1,
       (case when l.PatientVisitCluster=2 then t.Result end) as t2
from tPatientLabTestData t left join 
     tPatientLabTest l
     on t.tPatientLabTestId = l.Id
where l.PatientId = @PatientId and 
      l.Volgnar = @Volgnar and 
      l.TestTypeListId = @LabTestId
```

It returns result like this.

[image]

I need desired result like below:

```
t1     t2
22     120
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use aggregation:

```
select max(case when l.PatientVisitCluster = 1 then t.Result end) as t1,
       max(case when l.PatientVisitCluster = 2 then t.Result end) as t2
from tPatientLabTestData t left join
     tPatientLabTest l
     on t.tPatientLabTestId=l.Id
where l.PatientId = @PatientId and
      l.Volgnar = @Volgnar and
      l.TestTypeListId = @LabTestId;
```

If you wanted this for all combinations of the three columns, include `group by`:

```
select l.PatientId, l.Volgnar, l.TestTypeListId,
       max(case when l.PatientVisitCluster = 1 then t.Result end) as t1,
       max(case when l.PatientVisitCluster = 2 then t.Result end) as t2
from tPatientLabTestData t left join
     tPatientLabTest l
     on t.tPatientLabTestId=l.Id

group by l.PatientId, l.Volgnar, l.TestTypeListId;
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be faster to just add a filtering condition in the WHERE clause, to return only PatientVisitCluster with values of 1 and 2?

Comment: adding a filtering condition on any of those columns would get rid of a row.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `PIVOT`

```
select PatientId, Volgnar, TestTypeListId, [1] t1, [2] t2
from tPatientLabTestData t 
left join tPatientLabTest l on t.tPatientLabTestId=l.Id
pivot (max(result) for PatientVisitCluster in ([1], [2])) p
```